# Insert ignoring data in formview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

The aspx code below is part of my asp:FormView which is populated from a external datasource (a separate table that this will eventually feed back into). The user is not allowed to make changes directly to the TextBox but can update the text box by making selections to the dropdownlist which will alter the value in the TextBox. This code works perfectly.

```
<asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableCell Width="25px">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" OnTextChanged="AssetTypeTextBox_TextChanged" ID="AssetTypeTextBox" Width="25px" Readonly = "true" Text='<%#Bind("AssetType") %>' />
</asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell Width="400px">
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="AssetTypeTextLabel" Text="Blank"></asp:Label>
</asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="AssetTypeDDL_SelectedIndexChanged" ID="AssetTypeDDL" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"> </asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="34">DB2 Cluster</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">Desktop</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="44">DNS Appliance</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="37">EXCH Resource Cluster</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="18">Firewall</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="12">HyperV Cluster</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="11">HyperV Guest Appliance</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="10">HyperV Guest OS</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="17">IDS/IPS Device</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="15">IBM PwrX Blade Server</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="14">IBM PwrX Server</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="52">IDS/IPS Device</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">Laptop</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="6">Mac Desktop</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="7">Mac Laptop</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="50">Mainframe</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="19">Mainframe Tape</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="35">MFD/Printers</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="48">Net Access Card Ctl</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="47">Net IP Cameras</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="48">Net Video Converter</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="46">Net Video Recorder</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="21">Network Appliance</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="52">Network Appliance (Virtual)</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="51">Network Supervisor</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="22">Physical Tape</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="42">Rack</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="43">Remote Mgmt</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Router</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="20">SAN Device</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="27">Server Enclosure</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="33">SQL Cluster</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Switch</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="8">ThinClient</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="5">UNIX Workstation</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="26">VIOS Cluster(NR)</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="16">VIOS Guest OS</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="45">VLE Cluster</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="25">VMWare Guest OS</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="40">VOIP Analog Fax</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="24">VOIP Gateway</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="23">VOIP Phone</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="41">VOIP Virtual Address</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="32">Windows FO Cluster</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="9">x86 Blade Server</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="13">x86 Standard Server</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</asp:TableCell>
```

I'm using the following code behind to process insert:

```
protected void InsertButton_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    ChangeFormFV.InsertItem(true);
    Response.Redirect("InvList.aspx");
  }
```

Upon clicking 'Insert', whatever values were on the FormView regardless of what changes have been made by the user will be written to the database in the insert.  This seems to defy logic to me.  I would think that the values present in the form at the time that the InsertItem(true) was initialized would be written to the table not what was first there when the screen was drawn.

Any thoughts on correcting this issue?

Sean, here is a larger clipping of the c# for you:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CInTrac
{
    public partial class Update : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox uname = (TextBox)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("SubmitByTextBox");
            if (uname != null)
                uname.Text = Session["RegUser"].ToString();

            TextBox udate = (TextBox)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("SubmitDTTextBox");
            if (udate != null)
                udate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

            // AssetID
            Label ustuff = (Label)RefDataFV.Row.FindControl("AssetIDLabel");
            if (ustuff != null)
                Session["AID"] = ustuff.Text;

            TextBox AIDvalue = (TextBox)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("AssetIDTextBox");

            if (AIDvalue != null)
                AIDvalue.Text = Session["AID"].ToString();
            // End of AssetID

            // AssetType
            Label atlstuff = (Label)RefDataFV.Row.FindControl("AssetTypeLabel");
            TextBox ATypevalue = (TextBox)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("AssetTypeTextBox");
                if (ATypevalue != null)
                ATypevalue.Text = atlstuff.Text;
                Session["AssetType"] = atlstuff.Text;

                GetAssetTypeFV.DataBind();
            Label astylbl = (Label)GetAssetTypeFV.Row.FindControl("AssetTypeLabel");
            Label ATTL = (Label)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("AssetTypeTextLabel");
            if (ATTL != null)
                ATTL.Text = astylbl.Text;
            // End of AssetType

            // AssetName
            Label anlstuff = (Label)RefDataFV.Row.FindControl("AssetNameLabel");
            TextBox ANamevalue = (TextBox)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("AssetNameTextBox");
            if (ANamevalue != null)
                ANamevalue.Text = anlstuff.Text;
            // End of AssetName

            // AssetShortDesc
            Label asdstuff = (Label)RefDataFV.Row.FindControl("AssetShortDescLabel");
            TextBox AShortDescvalue = (TextBox)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("AssetShortDescTextBox");
            if (AShortDescvalue != null)
                AShortDescvalue.Text = asdstuff.Text;
            // End of AssetShortDesc
   
   // CLIPPED HERE to remove repeated copy of data from one data source to the other
   // Also clipped from here for brevity are routines that hide/show pannels of indidvidaul fields
   // based on ACL values of users
   
            }
        protected void AssetTypeDDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList pick = (DropDownList)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("AssetTypeDDL");
            TextBox ATypevalue = (TextBox)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("AssetTypeTextBox");
            if (ATypevalue != null)
                ATypevalue.Text = pick.SelectedValue.ToString();
            Label ATTL = (Label)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("AssetTypeTextLabel");
            if (ATTL != null)
                ATTL.Text = pick.SelectedItem.Text;
        }

        protected void AssetStatusDdl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList pick = (DropDownList)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("AssetStatusDdl");
            TextBox AStatusvalue = (TextBox)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("AssetStatusTextBox");
            if (AStatusvalue != null)
                AStatusvalue.Text = pick.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }

        protected void AssetPropTypeDdl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList pick = (DropDownList)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("AssetPropTypeDdl");
            TextBox APropTypevalue = (TextBox)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("AssetPropTypeTextBox");
            if (APropTypevalue != null)
                APropTypevalue.Text = pick.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }

        protected void AssetCompany1Ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList pick = (DropDownList)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("AssetCompany1Ddl");
            TextBox ACompanyvalue = (TextBox)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("AssetCompanyTextBox");
            if (ACompanyvalue != null)
                ACompanyvalue.Text = pick.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }

        protected void AssetPriOSDdl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList pick = (DropDownList)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("AssetPriOSDdl");
            TextBox APriOSvalue = (TextBox)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("AssetPriOSTextBox");
            if (APriOSvalue != null)
                APriOSvalue.Text = pick.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }

        protected void AssetAdminGrpDdl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList pick = (DropDownList)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("AssetAdminGrpDdl");
            TextBox AAdminGrpvalue = (TextBox)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("AssetAdminGrpTextBox");
            if (AAdminGrpvalue != null)
                AAdminGrpvalue.Text = pick.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }

        protected void AssetOperStatusDDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList pick = (DropDownList)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("AssetOperStatusDDL");
            TextBox AOperStatusvalue = (TextBox)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("AssetOperStatusTextBox");
            if (AOperStatusvalue != null)
                AOperStatusvalue.Text = pick.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }

        protected void InsertButton_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChangeFormFV.InsertItem(true);
            Response.Redirect("InvList.aspx");
        }

        protected void AssetTypeTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }
    }

}​
```

Comment: We don't really have enough information to help here. I am totally guessing here but are you binding the text box values on form load? If so, perhaps you are setting the value of the textbox before the click even fires. Maybe you can add a check to not populate the values if it a postback. Without more code from your page though it is just guessing.

Comment: Thought that I had explained that but let me expand a bit. The data populated in the form is from souse A.  We are bound to source B and are seeding the data collected from A into the formview bound to B then rendering it to the screen in 'insert mode'. At this point prior to clicking the 'insert button, the user has the opportunity to choose dropdownlists and alter text boxes on the form. Then the content of the form should be inserted. However, what is inserted is only the original data provide from datasource A (which isn't bound).

Comment: Right I get that. Did you see my guess? I am betting you are binding the textbox value to SourceA in form load. So when you click the button it binds the value before you have a chance to insert it. Remember that FormLoad fires BEFORE your click event happens. This means that it is entirely possible you have the correct value in the textbox and then overwrite it with values from SourceA. Again, posting some more code would make this a lot easier as we can't see anything other than what is posted.

Comment: No that is not the case.  Source A is not linked in any way to this formview. All data is transitioned into the form via code behind passing of values from one to the other.  So we are working on a copy of the soruce data.

Comment: I am guessing because you haven't share enough information for anybody to help here. If you can't share some code so we can help then there is nothing I can do. I can't see your screen or read your mind. And yes Source A IS linked to this form. You even state the data is transitioned here....whatever that means.

Comment: I can assure you that they are not Sean.  BUT... Our discussion here has raised an issue that I think may be causing some of the problem that I hadn't considered.  What do you think of this. Source A and Source B are nearly identical layouts except Source B is a super set of A in that it has some operational control fields added to track and control the process. So the columns that that are duplicated are exactly that exact duplicates in every way.  If both datasources are open at the same time could that be causing issues?

Comment: No that will not affect this. I don't know why you continue to refuse to share code so that others may help. Good luck.

Comment: Sean, I'm not refusing anything. Just wouldn't be practical to paste my entire project in here. I don't know what else I could give you that would help you help me.  This is the core of the information. Tell me what you'd like to see and I will try to provide it.

Comment: I have mentioned FormLoad several times. Of course it reasonable to upload the entire project. But look at what I can see of your project. A bunch of markup of which only a couple of lines have any bearing since most of it is just values. And a single two line method. Which would need the insert method of your object at the very least to have ANY meaning. Think about the sections of code relevant to this insert, that is where you have to start looking. I am 99.99999% certain that is based on not fully understanding the page lifecycle and some event is happening earlier than you think.

Comment: You don't have a FormLoad method? What method are you using to load your data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125947/discussion-between-sean-lange-and-ken-carter).

Comment: Posting has been updated with additional code behind. Going back to our discussion page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure that through our lengthy discussion this is related the order of events during Page_Load. The page load events fires BEFORE the button click event so the values in your dropdowns and such were getting modified before you tried to insert them. Simply check during Page_Load:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
```

This should get you around the issue you are having.